# how to use Mysql trigger 'leave', 'switch' commands

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have trigger as in the following example:

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON icharts_user_stats FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF (NEW.col1> OLD.col1
    OR NEW.col2 > OLD.col2) THEN 
    SET NEW.col3 =  NEW.col3+1;
    SET NEW.col4 =  NEW.col4+1; END  IF;

IF (NEW.col5> OLD.col5
    OR NEW.col6 > OLD.col6) THEN 
    SET NEW.col7 =  NEW.col7+1; END  IF;

IF (NEW.col8> OLD.col8
    OR NEW.col9 > OLD.col9) THEN 
    SET NEW.col10 =  NEW.col10+1; END  IF;
```

This is something like switch statements, at any point only one 'if' will be executed. The above code works, but if the first 'if' is hit, it will still go through all the other ifs.

1. Is there a better way to do it ?
2. Is using 'leave' just before 'end if' a good idea

Thanks

Comment: or use [elseif](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html)  Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056783/how-do-i-exit-a-series-of-if-else-conditions-in-a-mysql-trigger

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON icharts_user_stats FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF (NEW.col1> OLD.col1
        OR NEW.col2 > OLD.col2) THEN 
        SET NEW.col3 =  NEW.col3+1;
        SET NEW.col4 =  NEW.col4+1; 

    ELSEIF (NEW.col5> OLD.col5
        OR NEW.col6 > OLD.col6) THEN 
        SET NEW.col7 =  NEW.col7+1; 

    ELSEIF (NEW.col8> OLD.col8
        OR NEW.col9 > OLD.col9) THEN 
        SET NEW.col10 =  NEW.col10+1; END  IF;
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try elseif, was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Let's say we have Condition1, Condition2 and Condition3 above. If Condition1 is true, it doesn't care or check Condition2 and Condition3. If Condition2 is true, it doesn't go check Condition3. It does meet your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON icharts_user_stats FOR EACH ROW 
icharts_user_stats:BEGIN

IF (NEW.col1> OLD.col1
    OR NEW.col2 > OLD.col2) THEN 
    SET NEW.col3 =  NEW.col3+1;
    SET NEW.col4 =  NEW.col4+1; 
    leave icharts_user_stats;
END  IF;

IF (NEW.col5> OLD.col5
    OR NEW.col6 > OLD.col6) THEN 
    SET NEW.col7 =  NEW.col7+1; 
    leave icharts_user_stats;
END  IF;

IF (NEW.col8> OLD.col8
    OR NEW.col9 > OLD.col9) THEN 
    SET NEW.col10 =  NEW.col10+1; 
    leave icharts_user_stats;
END  IF;
```

Comment: This one should be the accepted solution. Tested on MySQL 8.0 and works as described.